# Can I declare a placeholder variable in parent class, and declare it in different types in child classes?

Tags: c++, parent-child

Can I somehow declare masiv in the parent class, so the destructor can work properly, or do I need to basically copy-paste the code for each child-class?

```
class Parent{
public:
    int X;
    int Y;
    // I want to declare a placeholder "masiv" here.

    ~Parent()
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < Y; i++)
            delete [] masiv[i];
        delete [] masiv;
    }
};

class Child1 : public Parent {
public:
    int* *masiv;
    // Create method
};

class Child2 : public Parent {
public:
    float* *masiv;
    // Create method
};
```

Note: The child classes share other methods, that are identical, but for the sake of simplicity, I didn't add them to the code. However, I'd like to add them to the parent as well, but I can't, as "masiv" isn't declared there.

EDIT: The templates worked wonders! Do note that I'm still fairly new into programming, and I didn't know about their existence (and how to use them) until now.

Comment: I think you would have to make the Parent class a template. [https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class_template](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class_template)

Comment: What about using std::vector<int> and std::vector<float> in Child classes and remove Parent destructor then?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can be easily achieved by template

```
template<typename T>
class Parent{
public:
    int X;
    int Y;
    // I want to declare a placeholder "masiv" here.
    T** masiv;

virtual ~Parent()  // not an option the virtual destructor
{
    for(int i = 0; i < Y; i++)
      delete [] masiv[i];
    }
    delete [] masiv;
};

class Child : public Parent<int>
{
   // you already have int* masiv here;
}
```

HOWEVER how the snippet is written and the reason you want to declare in parent class is mostly a bad design and you're treating it as an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem),

Comment: worth mentioning that this is different from OPs code, because if one class inherits from `Parent<int>` and the other from `Parent<float>` then they are not sharing a common base class

Comment: _"HOWEVER how the snippet is written and the reason you want to declare in parent class is mostly a bad design and you're treating it as an XY problem"_ How so? Lots of assertions here.

Comment: That did work! My design turned out this way, because I started writing a version for my class, using int, and another version for my class, using float. Then I decided to make a parent class, that holds all the similarities of the two to reduce the code length. The X and Y are just variables that my Child classes used to both have, so I gave them to the Parent.

Answer (score 1):

The "right" thing to do is for `Child1` and `Child2` to have destructors that clean up the resources owned and specified by *those* classes. In this case, yes, that means you'd have identical `delete[] masiv` lines (et al), though this is no big burden.

If you have loads of these and *really* don't want to go down that route, use a smart pointer that cleans itself up.

Alternatively, you could have an intermediate base class template, that owns (and manages) a `T** masiv` and derives from `Parent`; then `Child1` would derives from `YourBase<int>` and `Child2` would derives from `YourBase<float>` using the Curiously Recurring Template Pattern. That's way overkill for the very specific simple example you've shown, though.

```
class Parent
{
public:
    int X;
    int Y;
    
    // Consider a virtual destructor here; depends what you're doing
};

template <typename T>
class MasivManager : public Parent
{
public:
    T** masiv;
    
    ~MasivManager()
    {
        for (std::size_t i = 0; i < Y; i++)
            delete[] masiv[i];
        delete[] masiv;
    }
};

class Child1 : public MasivManager<int> {};
class Child2 : public MasivManager<float> {};
```

You could give this job to `Parent` itself by making it a template:

```
template <typename T>
class Parent
{
public:
    int X;
    int Y;
    T** masiv;
    
    // Consider making this a virtual destructor; depends what you're doing
    ~Parent()
    {
        for (std::size_t i = 0; i < Y; i++)
            delete[] masiv[i];
        delete[] masiv;
    }
};

class Child1 : public Parent<int> {};
class Child2 : public Parent<float> {};
```

However, whether this "makes sense" depends on its semantics in your application, and we can't see that. Is it logical that a `Parent` owns a `masiv`? Will every kind of `Parent` do so? (Based on where `X` and `Y` live, I'm thinking, "yes", but only you can decide.)

You'd also be losing the common base class (since template specialisations are distinct types), though you may or may not care about that.

Comment: Thing is, that I am giving a simplified version of my code. It's not just the destructor method that my child classes share, yet most of the methods look identical, and most of them use this "masiv".

Comment: @WereElf You said nothing about that in your question. :( Still, I stand by my answer: I think I've described all the patterns I'd consider in this scenario.